# Views Don't Update Until MapView is Touched

Tags: android, android-maps

I have an Activity that mostly consists of a large MapView.  On top of that MapView, I have a couple of other Views that I'm attempting to interact with programmatically.

My first problem occurred when I tried to use an AnimationListener to animate one of the Views on top of the MapView.  The AnimationListener would not fire until I touched the MapView.  This was fixed by ditching the AnimationListener and calling `setVisibility()` and other code sequentially.  It's not ideal, but it works fine.

My current problem occurs when trying to update a TextView that's on top of the MapView.  I set the text, but it doesn't display until I physically touch the MapView.  I've tried requesting focus and other things but to no avail.

Has anybody else experienced this and come up with a working solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `map.invalidate()` to refresh the `MapView`

Comment: from where should i call this method?

Answer (score 2):

you only need to wite the below code when your layout creates for mapview.

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapViewUsers);
    mapView.onCreate(bundleSavedInstanceState);
    mapView.onResume();//need to respond immediatly from mapview.
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(context.getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
```