# Update the UI from background thread during touch event

Tags: android, android-mapview, handler

I'm trying to add an overlay to a MapView from a background thread to optically mark the point the user is currently touching.

At the moment I try to achieve that using Timer/Handler.
When the MotionEvent is ACTION_DOWN, I post a task, which adds the circle overlay to the mapView overlays after a certain delay.

Unfortunately, the UI is only updated after the user removes the finger from the screen (ACTION_UP).

Here's the sample code:

**UI thread**

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    handler = new OverlayHandler(mapView, centerDrawer) // centerDrawer is an overlay drawing a circle
    cTask = new DrawTimer(handler); // Calls handler.sendMessage, telling the handler to add centerDraw to the overlays of mapView

    handler.postDelayed(cTast, delay);

} else {
    handler.removeCallbacks(cTask);
}
```

**Timer (DrawTimer etc.)**

```
public void run() {
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = 1;
    handler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

**Handler**

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
    case 1:
            mapView.getOverlays().add(centerDrawer);
    break;
        // more cases
    }
    super.handleMessage(msg);
}
```

As far as I know, this is the default way to interact with the UI from a background task.

Is this also valid for updates while the user is interacting with the screen?
Do I have to explicitly tell the view to render new overlays?

**EDIT:**

The code should do the following:
On touch, it should start to observe how long the user keeps touching. After an inital delay, the circle should be added to the view. After some more delay, another overlay is added and so forth.

I do that for each overlay in two steps: 
I add a Runnable to handler to be executed after a delay. The Runnable then sends the corresponding message to the handler, telling it, what to draw.
I'm doing it like that, because...

- I need to be able to cancel the timer (the post), if the user moves or releases its finger.
- Some overlays should change, when the user keeps touching the screen. The postDelayed Runnable just keeps sending messages till canceled.

That's why I don't just use delayed messages.

**Use cases**

- User touches screen -> user releases before delay passes (nothing should appear)
- Touch -> delay passes -> circle -> release
- Touch -> delay passes -> circle -> delay 2 passes -> circle 2 -> release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in this question: 
[Views Don't Update Until MapView is Touched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697465/views-dont-update-until-mapview-is-touched)

mapView.invalidate() forces the view to redraw all its overlays. It might not be the most efficient way to implement that behavior but it works the way I want it to.

Thanks to farble1670 for pointing at some problems with my prior implementation.
Following his advice I changed it to use messages only (which are cancelable as well using removeMessage).

The new code is even simpler:

**UI Thread**

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    handler = new OverlayHandler(mapView, centerDrawer)

    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, d);

} else {
    handler.removeMessage(1);
}
```

**Handler**

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
    case 1:
        mapView.getOverlays().add(centerDrawer);
    break;
        // more cases
    }
    mapView.invalidate(); // Forces redrawing of all overlays
    super.handleMessage(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your comment says "calls handler.sendMessage ...", but then you subsequently post delayed to the handler. You either want to call sendMessage, or postDelayed, but not both. You are putting the message on the queue 2x. That doesn't necessarily explain your issue though.

You should post the code for DelayTimer, and check what the value of delay.

Comment: The Runnable added in postDelayed is executed after the delay. It then (after the delay), tells the Handler to update UI. I'm not posting the same information twice to the queue.
I need to do that, because I need to be able to cancel the drawing, if the user removes its finger before the delay has passed.
I clarify my question with this information.

Comment: postDelayed() is not an exact timer. the UI message queue handles things as it has time to do so, so it's possible for example that your two messages are processed at about the same time. i can't say that's a cause of your issue but it is possibly a problem in your code. have you added log statements to see when exactly you are getting the ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN events?

Comment: Well, funnily, if I use sendMessageAtTime, the circle appears while touching. You might be right that there is an issue with the Runnables. I dig into it, thanks for pointing at that!

Comment: just a comment in general ... users understand press and long press. if you are inventing a new pattern other than that, you might want to rethink things. it's not going to be intuitive to users.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I want to provide a method to select a point on a map and then choose a radius around it. If I manage to make it work there should be a dot showing the center and a growing ring representing the radius. This just seemed like an easy (TM) way without having the user to type or perform gestures.